# Maior e menor valor

Tags: java

> Faça um programa que receba um conjunto de valores inteiros e positivos e que calcule e mostre o maior e o menor valor do conjunto. (Para encerrar a entrada, deve ser digitado o valor zero).

Eu sei que a parte do menor valor está errada, pois a dúvida é exatamente conseguir o menor valor, o maior valor está correto.

```
package exercices2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MaiorEMenor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double valor = 1;
        double valorMaior = 0;
        double valorMenor = 0;
        for(;valor!=0;) {
            System.out.println("Digite os valores (0 para parar):");
            valor = input.nextDouble();
            if(valor > valorMaior && valor!=0) {
                valorMaior = valor;

            }
            if(valor < valorMenor && valor!=0) {
                valorMenor = valor;
            }   
        }
        System.out.println("Maior valor: "+ valorMaior);
        System.out.println("Menor valor: "+ valorMenor);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O que aconteceu no seu código de errado? Você definiu valores iniciais ruins. Note que no enunciado não foi definido que os números serão estritamente positivos. A seguinte entrada daria o resultado errada para o `valorMaior` porém certo para `valorMenor`:

> ```
> -1.0 -10.0 -7.0 0
> ```

Por que vai dar valor errado? Porque você está pegando um valor de *fora da lista* e usando como base.

Sem usar Java 8, a solução seria pegar o primeiro número como algo especial. Eu vejo três alternativas:

1. a leitura do primeiro número ser considerada especial
2. usar alguma marcação para indicar que é a primeira leitura e fazer o tratamento especial, como usar o *wrapper* `Double` para guardar os valores máximo e mínimo da lista inicializado com `null`
3. armazenar numa lista e então tratar como se estivesse no caso 1

#### Primeira leitura especial

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
double valorLido = input.nextDouble();
double menor, maior;
menor = maior = valorLido; // inicializo ambos os valores maior e menor com o primeiro valor lido
while (valorLido != 0) {
  valorLido = input.nextDouble();
  if (valorLido != 0) {
    if (valorLido > maior) {
      maior = valorLido;
    } else if (valorLido < menor) {
       menor = valorLido;
    }
  }
}

System.out.println("maior " + maior);
System.out.println("menor " + menor);
```

Tratei a primeira leitura de modo especial. Inicializei os valores básicos e só então fui atrás de saber como atualizar para novos valores.

Note que devido ao princípio da boa ordenação, se `a > b` e `b > c`, então tenho que `a > c`. Logo não tem como eu atualizar o valor maior e, ao mesmo tempo, atualizar o valor menor. Então, devido a isso, eu coloquei um `else if` no lugar de sempre verificar se se deve atualizar o menor valor oi não.

Marcação da primeira leitura via *wrapper*

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
Double menor, maior;
menor = maior = null;

while (true) {
  double valorLido = input.nextDouble();
  if (valorLido == 0) {
    break;
  }
  if (maior == null) {
    // marcação da primeira leitura, devo atualizar ambos os valores de maior e menor
    maior = menor = valorLido;
  } else if (valorLido > maior) {
    // já caiu no caso else, então não é primeira leitura
    maior = valorLido;
  } else if (valorLido < menor) {
    menor = valorLido;
  }
}
System.out.println("maior " + maior);
System.out.println("menor " + menor);
```

#### Marcação da primeira leitura usando um booleano

É absurdamente semelhante. Só que aqui eu devo inicializar com valores arbitrários (escolhi `NaN`) os valores de `maior` e `menor`.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
double menor, maior;
menor = maior = Double.NaN;
boolean primeiraLeitura = true;

while (true) {
  double valorLido = input.nextDouble();
  if (valorLido == 0) {
    break;
  }
  if (primeiraLeitura) {
    // marcação da primeira leitura, devo atualizar ambos os valores de maior e menor
    maior = menor = valorLido;
    primeiraLeitura = false; // marcando para não ler novamente
  } else if (valorLido > maior) {
    // já caiu no caso else, então não é primeira leitura
    maior = valorLido;
  } else if (valorLido < menor) {
    menor = valorLido;
  }
}
System.out.println("maior " + maior);
System.out.println("menor " + menor);
```

#### Armazenar em uma lista

Essa alternativa é trivial. Jogue a leitura para um `ArrayList` e depois trate os valores dentro dele.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<Double> lista = new ArrayList<>();

double valorLido;
while (true) {
  valorLido = input.nextDouble();
  if (valorLido == 0) {
    break;
  }
  lista.add(valorLido);
}
double maior, menor;
maior = menor = lista.get(0);
for (Double valor: lista) {
  if (valor > maior) {
    maior = valor;
  } else if (valor < menor) {
    menor = valor;
  }
}
System.out.println("maior " + maior);
System.out.println("menor " + menor);
```

#### Usando *stream API* do Java 8

Eu poderia usar diversas alternativas, mas a mais rápida é usando a [`DoubleSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/DoubleSummaryStatistics.html). Para isso vou usar um coletor especial: [`Collectors.summarizingDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summarizingDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-). Estou adaptando [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32565520/4438007) do Stack Overflow internacional.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<Double> lista = new ArrayList<>();

double valorLido;
while (true) {
  valorLido = input.nextDouble();
  if (valorLido == 0) {
    break;
  }
  lista.add(valorLido);
}
DoubleSummaryStatistics summary = lista.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingDouble(Double::doubleValue));
double maior = summary.getMax();
double menor = summary.getMin();
System.out.println("maior " + maior);
System.out.println("menor " + menor);
```