# Como transformar uma leitura de números diretamente em stream?

Tags: java, java-8

Recentemente eu [escrevi uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/286018/64969) explorando um pouco mais a API de `stream` do Java 8, mas devo dizer que fiquei decepcionado com alguns detalhes do meu código.

A ideia era ler uma sequência de números e retornar então qual o maior e o menor valor das leituras realizadas. No caso, a entrada terminava quando era introduzido o número 0.

Eu não sei como usar de maneira hábil um iterável com as APIs de `stream`. Então resolvi ir pelo método porco e objetivo: eu sei ler dados e jogar em um `ArrayList` para então usar esta lista tranquilamente para `stream`. O código resultante foi este:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
ArrayList<Double> lista = new ArrayList<>();

double valorLido;
while (true) {
  valorLido = input.nextDouble();
  if (valorLido == 0) {
    break;
  }
  lista.add(valorLido);
}
DoubleSummaryStatistics summary = lista.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingDouble(Double::doubleValue));
double maior = summary.getMax();
double menor = summary.getMin();
System.out.println("maior " + maior);
System.out.println("menor " + menor);
```

Esse código não me agradou. Gostaria de conseguir usar diretamente o resultado da leitura para passar à `stream` sem necessidade de transformar em qualquer tipo de coleção.

Por exemplo, se fosse para eu obter um iterável das leituras, faria assim:

```
Iterable<Double> leitorDoubleAteh0(Scanner in) {
  return () -> new Iterator<Double>() {
    boolean conseguiuFetch;
    double valorFetch;
    void fetchNext() {
        valorFetch = in.nextDouble();
        conseguiuFetch = valorFetch != 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
      return conseguiuFetch;
    }

    @Override
    public Double next() {
      if (!conseguiuFetch) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("fim da leitura");
      }
      double valorRetorno = valorFetch;
      fetchNext();
      return valorRetorno;
    }

    {
      fetchNext();
    }
  };
}
```

Isso no mínimo me daria acesso ao `foreach`, mas ainda assim não é o meu desejado `stream`.

Comment: Não sei se percebi em pleno a questão, mas se a ideia é como passar de forma direta ao `min` e `max` dá para fazer sem coletar com `lista.stream().max(Double::compare).get()` uma vez que o `max` e `min` da stream levam um *Comparator*

Comment: Justo, mas isso não explica como transformar uma sequência de leitura em um stream sem passar por uma coleção.

Comment: O grande problema aqui é que lendo do console você não recebe um EOF. Uma solução com um número de linhas conhecido é elegante, mas te ajuda?

Comment: @JulianoAlves número conhecido e limitado não seria meu foco. A intenção é evitar carregar uma lista inteira na memória. Gostaria de trabalhar com stream usando `o(1)` memória, não `o(n)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com o [método `Stream.generate(Supplier<? extends T>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate(java.util.function.Supplier)), você pode ler os números do `Scanner` sem precisar do `ArrayList`.

Eu sei que a tag é [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8). Mas se você aceitar usar Java 9 ou superior, pode usar o [método `Stream.takeWhile(Predicate<? super T>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile(java.util.function.Predicate)) para fazer o critério de parada.

Eis o resultado:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
DoubleSummaryStatistics summary = Stream
        .generate(input::nextDouble)
        .takeWhile(z -> z != 0)
        .collect(Collectors.summarizingDouble(Double::doubleValue));
double maior = summary.getMax();
double menor = summary.getMin();
System.out.println("maior " + maior);
System.out.println("menor " + menor);
```

Comment: Tenho limitações no código para o Java 8 (suporte do GWT e do TotalCross, nas versões usadas só dão suporte ao Java 8), mas óbvio que aceito sugestões novas. Estou negociando com o pessoal de operações para tentar subir para Java 10 em teste