# Como validar os elementos produzidos durante um Java Stream antes do collect?

Tags: java, java-8

Dado o exemplo hipotético abaixo como seria a melhor maneira de validar todos os elementos produzidos por um Java Stream, no exemplo abaixo gostaria de verificar se todos os elementos produzidos são pares ou lançar um erro.

```
Set result = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9).stream()
    .filter( n -> n % 2 == 0)
    //Validar aqui se todos são pares ou lançar uma Exception
    .map(String::valueOf)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

Comment: Mas o `filter` já pegou somente os números pares, para que verificar de novo se todos são pares? Ou vc quer lançar uma exceção se não tiver nenhum par?

Comment: É um exemplo hipotético, a validação poderia ser se todos os pares são menores ou iguais a 10, o objetivo e fazer uma validação qualquer que seja.

Comment: Talvez  usar [`allMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) resolva. O problema é que esta é uma [operação terminal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) e não será possível usar `collect` depois. Talvez seja mais simples incluir todas as condições no `filter` e no final verificar se o `Set` é vazio, por exemplo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução relativamente elegante seria utilizar o anymatch para verificar se existe algum cenário onde você deveria lançar a exception e em um segundo momento, caso não houvesse exception, você seguiria com seu processamento normalmente, não necessitando captura afinal já foi validado que seus dados estão coerentes.

```java
        Set<Integer> result = (Set<Integer>) Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);

        if(result.stream().anyMatch(n -> n % 2 != 0)){
            throw new Exception();
        }

        {seu código}
```

Considerando o fato que o lambda não é executado exatamente no local onde ele foi escrito, mas em algum lugar "magico" e não relacionado da sua jdk esse local seria onde sua exception seria checada, não interrompendo execução. Para solucionarmos isso devemos criar um wrapper que tem por objetivo traduzir uma exception checada para uma não checada e "estourar" a falha.

```java
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Set result = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9).stream()
                    .filter(n ->uncheckCall(() -> {
                        if(n % 2 == 0){
                            return true;
                        }else{
                            throw new Exception();
                        }
                    }))
                    .map(String::valueOf)
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());

            System.out.println(result);
        }

        public static <T> T uncheckCall(Callable<T> callable) {
            try {
                return callable.call();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Pessoalmente prefiro a primeira solução, mas fica ai uma segunda possibilidade.

Comment: No meu cenário a segunda opção se enquadra melhor

Comment: Eu acho mais adequado usar o `peek` no lugar do `filter`. Coloquei isso com mais detalhes na minha resposta

Answer (score 2):

Pegando a segunda solução da [resposta do @Scarabelo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/403179/64969), porém adaptando para algo mais indicado.

O desejado não é fazer um filtro, mas sim uma *bizoiada* (palavra advinda do cearencês neoclássico). Essa olhadela é feita em cada elemento do elemento, e ele é passado adiante no fluxo da *stream*. É o método [`Stream<T>.peek(Consumer<? super T>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-). Com ele, você pode simplesmente executar, sem se preocupar com retorno.

No seu exemplo:

```java
Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9).stream()
  .peek(n -> {
    if (n % 2 != 0) {
      throw new RunTimeException();
    }
  })
  .map(String::valueOf)
  .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Você pode colocar o `peek()` em qualquer momento antes da operação terminal da `Stream`, já que ele é uma operação intermediária.

---

Sobre a primeira opção da [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/403179/64969), eu não sou favorável a ela por dois motivos:

1. a `Stream` pode não ser "rebobinável" ([exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/286810/64969))
2. vai percorrer sempre duas vezes a coleção de elementos

A segunda solução usa uma quantidade maior de memória no caso de falhas, mas o processamento é feito apenas uma única vez.